# How to run PHP background operations / handle methods in different request?

Tags: php, symfony

I am running a `Symfony 2.8` based web app. Basically Each request to the server is handled in three steps:

```
 1. User/Browser sends request to the server
 2. Server handles the request and performs any number of operations
 3. Server sends back the result as response to the user
```

When testing the WebApp performance (= time between request and response) I came across the problem, that my code runs a bunch of code which is just maintenance and not really necessary to create the response: Writing logs, adding information of the request to stats, etc.

```
 2. Server handles the request and performs any number of operations
     2a. Necessary work to answer the request
     2b. Maintenance work
```

The user would get exactly the same response if code would simple skip all these steps and only run the code which is really necessary to create the response.

**Is it somehow possible to move this work to background / another request to separate the maintenance work from the "real" work and create the response faster?**

Is this possible in PHP or maybe using a Symfony feature?

**To be more precise:** Of course *"my code runs a bunch of code which is just maintenance..."* does NOT mean that each request needs 30 seconds to be handled and that removing the maintenance code would reduce this a few milliseconds.

I am well aware that removing this stuff would not boost the performance and keeping some maintenance code within the "real" code is the much better solution than moving everything "to the background".

This is more a general question on "How to move heavy maintenance workload that is not necessary to handle a request to the background". Is this possible in PHP at all?

Comment: Aren't you in control over what symfony should log and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from other languages this migth be weird, but it is very natural for both PHP and Symfony.

The PHP lifecycle itself initializes, and shuts down everything on every request. This is great for safety (an error in one request wont effect other requests), but not so much for speed.

The same therefore applies to Symfony. A request comes in, a response is served, and everything shuts down (needs to be logged, flushed etc). (Sidenote: Sf is capable of handling multiple requests - look at PHP-PM)

**Luckily Symfony has a `kernel.terminate` event, which allows you to run code after the response has been sent.** http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#the-kernel-terminate-event

This is very useful for some stuff, but only works with php-fpm.
A good example is memory spooling for emails: https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/spool.html

Symfony delays the sending of emails after the response has been sent.

You could do the same for your use-case, just need a `kernel.terminate` listener. You mentioned some kind of request stat... this would be a great place to create and save that.

You also mentioned logging: I would not worry about it too much. In prod mode, only errors will get logged, thanks to the fingers-crossed handler. https://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/logging/monolog.html#handlers-and-channels-writing-logs-to-different-locations

> Monolog comes also with a powerful built-in handler for the logging in prod environment: FingersCrossedHandler. It allows you to store the messages in a buffer and to log them only if a message reaches the action level (ERROR in the configuration provided in the standard edition) by forwarding the messages to another handler.

You could also change the logging storage if you think logging to a file is too slow. I use an API (rollbar) to log errors, and it does not effect performance at all - unless there is an error, in which case the additional ~30ms response time is the least of my worries.

Comment: Thank you very much, `kernel.termiate` is a good solution in my case! However this only works if `PHP-FPM` is used. Otherwise the code in the `kernel.terminate` handler will still delay the the response. Another solution I found in the meanwhile is this bundle: https://github.com/krlove/async-service-call-bundle

Comment: If you are willing to separate this to it's own process, you could use messaging. A rabbitmq consumer would be a much better solution than an async process.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to run `index.php` at `2a`. Your requirement is that you dont want to wait for `index.php` to finish before sending the response.

You can do it as follow:

```
$cmd="php index.php";
if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
    pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));
} else {
    exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
}
```